# Disconnect Socket while using Forward & Backward navigation arrows in Angular App

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io

I am working on an Angular app that require a socket connection with the backend in the path '/room' (using socket.io-client library. Connection established in ngOnInit() of the main component of the path '/room'). The socket is disconnected in ngOnDestroy().

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.socket = io(environment.SOCKET_URI, {query: `roomId=${this.roomId}&username=${this.username}`});

  this.socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("Socket connection with server established");
  })

  this.socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    this.openSnackBar("You've left the room", "");
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
  })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.socket.emit('disconnect', '');
}
```

I use a node.js backend. I handle disconnection as follows:

```
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  socket.emit('message', 'Socket connection aborted');
  socket.disconnect(true);
}
```

If I navigate to another path imperatively i.e. typing the path directly on the URL bar or using a Router, the ngOnDestroy() function is called as well as the 'disconnect' callback in the backend.

But if I use the Backward or Forward navigation arrows in the browser, the ngOnDestroy() is called but the 'disconnect' callback in the backend is not triggered, and the socket continue to live in the backend. It's only after I refresh the new page that I navigated to that the callback is triggered and the socket disconnected completely.

What causes this behaviour ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I have to use the following command in the client side to disconnect the socket:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  // this.socket.emit('disconnect', '');
  this.socket.disconnect();
}
```

For some reason the disconnection while using backward and forward navigation arrows doesn't work with the previous command.